# Output to Eclipse console from jar running externally

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, console, output

I have been developing a Java app with Eclipse on Mac OS X. Up to this point, I have been running the app through Eclipse and printing to the Eclipse console with System.out.println().

After I bundle my jar into a Mac app and run it by itself, console output no longer works for obvious reasons. Is there any way to print to the Eclipse console from my externally running jar? Thanks for any help.

Comment: make little change in code,with the use of `out.println()` to write log in text file instead use `System.out.println()` this will make `Log` file to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run it from the command line.
2. run it from another Java program as a separate JVM process, and capture the InputStream, OutputStream, and ErrorStreams for input and output.